# Parâmetros no tratador de Sinais

Tags: c

Estou com uma dúvida e mesmo após pesquisa não consegui resolver.

Digamos que eu tenha o seguinte tratador de sinal:

```
struct sigaction conf_signal;
conf_signal.sa_flags = 0;
sigemptyset(&conf_signal.sa_mask);
conf_signal.sa_handler = &sinal_chegou;
```

E o seguinte código dentro de um for:

```
    if (sigaction(SIGINT, &conf_signal, NULL) == -1) {
        perror("sigaction");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
```

E a minha função `sinal_chegou` tem a seguinte assinatura:

```
void sinal_chegou(void){
```

Como eu faço pra enviar um parâmetro recebido no `argv[]` para a função `sinal_chegou` usando o tratador de sinal?

Answer (score 0):

Use uma variável global. Acho que não existe outra maneira.

Comment: Amigo, poste apenas respostas objetivas e concretas, utilize os comentários para este tipo de apontamento.